# Receiving HTTPXMLResponse 500 'Internal Service Error'

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xmlhttprequest, http-error

I am using an apache server, with javascript capturing form data and sending the form data to a PHP endpoint via an XHR.

Edit: my code runs fine locally, but returns a 500 internal server error as well as an uncaught syntax error on the live site.

Below is the XHR in the javascript file, the uncaught syntax error occurs at line 4 (`onload()`) and on line 5 (unexpected end of JSON input):

**index.js**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', submitUrl, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = () => {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(response);
    if (response.error === 'member-exists') {
        setAlreadySubscribed();
        showStatusAndHideForm();
    } else if (response.error === 'none') {
        setSuccess();
        showStatusAndHideForm();
    } else {
        alertUnknownError();
        enableForm();
      }
  }
  xhr.send(body);
})
```

And below is the PHP, which POSTs the data to an external API via cURL:

**submitUrl.php**

```
$ch = curl_init('https://foo');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
     CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
         'Authorization: apikey '.$authToken,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
     ),
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $userdata
 ),
 );

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I then decode the cURL `$result` to check for errors from the external API, encoding them to be sent back to the XHR.

Devtools shows the 500 error at line 18 of index.js.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Look in the server error log to find out why your PHP code is failing.

Comment: You have a stray comma in `curl_setopt_array()`. VTC typo. Proper indentation and modern coding practices such as `[]` instead of `array()` will help you spot these problems.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular -- the error is only happening on the live site, locally gives no internal server error

Comment: @rachel The problems with your AJAX call are caused by the PHP code on your server failing. If the problem occurs on the live server, look on the live server error log.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular could you advise on how to find the live server error log 

Comment: Unfortunately, hosting companies have different systems for this, depending on the level of your agreement with them. One company I dealt with placed a file called phperror.log in my account home directory (not the public html directory). I'm now on a dedicated server so the error log is where I configured Apache to put it. If you can't see it somewhere in your user account directory, ask your hosting company's support where to find it.